# Work needed to upgrade Zurb Foundation v5 to v6.2

Tags: zurb-foundation-5, zurb-foundation-6

What & how much work is required to upgrade Foundation 5 to 6.2?

Our dev shop is taking over development of an existing F5 project.  Seems the front-end layout is 80% complete, though we'll likely transition into JSX to little will be untouched.  I need help in weighing if F6.2 is worth the extra hassle, since the client is budget-limited.  [Zurb's F6 announcement](http://zurb.com/article/1416/foundation-6-is-here) lists only a few lower priority advantages (A11y, fewer classes).  Flexbox might be helpful, small Foundation CSS is less of a concern thanks to [UnCSS](https://github.com/giakki/uncss).

I've used F6.2 once, but would like to hear from folks who upgraded real sites from F5 to F6.x with gotchas & time needed.  There still is no [F5 to F6 upgrade guide](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7246), & [release notes are lacking](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/releases/tag/v6.0.0).

Comment: I've not done much with Foundation 6, but from what I know, the changes are mostly related to how plugins are initialized. The styles are pretty much the same (apart from button groups, which have been removed in F6 - other things may be missing). That's the extent of what I know regarding the differences. I haven't actually upgraded, so there may be more quirks you have to solve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upgrading from Foundation 5 to latest Foundation 6 involves a full website rebuild from a new website Template, because much of the HTML code is a bit different. No it is not difficult, but yes, there is a fair amount of work in making the transition. However, the numerous improvements are worth it.

You need to start a new website project in a new folder to get all the updated file sets, which are contained in these folders ...

- bower_components
- node_modules
- scss
- css

There are various ways to install Foundation for Sites 6, my preference being npm node package manager using the Command Prompt, like so :

foundation new
What are you building today? = A website (Foundation for Sites)
What's the project called = whatever_projectname
Which template would you like to use? = Basic Template: includes a Sass compiler

cd whatever_projectname

TO BUILD css\app.css using GULP
foundation build

TO UPDATE css\app.css
npm start
OR
foundation watch
CTRL+C to end

Once you have the new set of v6 files downloaded, then in the 'scss' folder you need to [customize the project SCSS files and regenerate the CSS](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html).

1. Open **_settings.scss** and modify entries as desired, basically to match what you had in previous v5.  Especially font-family, headings, font-size, colors, line-height, etc. All the $variable-names are different, but you will quickly get the gist of it.
2. Open **app.scss** and choose what @includes you want to import, just those you really do need so as to minimise final CSS filesize.
3. After all your @includes, then **you copy/paste in all the custom SCSS style code from your previous Foundation 5 website project**.
4. Now for the real work. You must convert all the Version 5 **MIXIN** and **MEDIA QUERY** code across to the new Version 6 format. Start by [reading the Foundation 6 Media Query page here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/media-queries.html).
   Your website software will surely have a 'Find' and 'Replace' feature, which is the best shot for this job. Here are some examples of :
   **OLD Foundation 5** scss code compared to the
   **NEW Foundation 6** format.
   @media #{$small-up}
   @include breakpoint(small)
   @media #{$large-up}
   @include breakpoint(large)
   @media #{$portrait}
   @include breakpoint(portrait)
   @include grid-column($columns:12);
   @include grid-column(12);
   @include flex-video-container();
   @include flex-video($flexvideo-ratio-widescreen);
   @include button($background:$primary-color);
   @include button($expand:false, $background:$primary-color, $background-hover:auto, $color:auto, $style:solid); font-size: 0.85rem;
5. Command Line Prompt 'foundation watch' generates your final **app.css** file upon each scss file save. If there is an **error** in your scss, GULP displays the Line Number where that error occurred. Read up, make necessary corrections and save again until **app.css** is generated without error.
6. View your Foundation 6 website test page, continue to tweak the CSS and, when happy with appearance, you will be ready to apply your new Foundation 6 Template to every page on the website.

**Foundation 5 ==> Foundation 6 conversion complete**.

The more conversions you do, the quicker and easier it becomes.

Comment: Thanks; will help my job estimate, & your workflow is very good.

BTW I have used F6.2 before, & have the following tips:

* [UnCSS](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) is essential to getting CSS file size down.  Also removes the worry of `@include` each module by hand.  (Dependency PhantomJS is tricky to install inside of Docker, otherwise easy to add to gulp workflow.)
* `@include foundation-everything(true)` [for flexbox](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/docs/pages/flexbox.md#enabling-flexbox-mode)

Comment: Starting from templates is a terrible practice. (It's basically copy-paste on steroids.) The other information you give -- regarding actual changes -- does sound useful though.

Comment: @aij Starting npm "**foundation new**" with "**What are you building today? = A website (Foundation for Sites)**" is just to get all latest version Foundation files downloaded into the new project folder. The actual website template I build using Adobe Dreamweaver and Sublime Text 3, which I prefer. Each website is a custom design, not copy/paste.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is much more involved than this (what is explained in the question). Following are the changes, which I had to apply to a (relatively simple project.) The amount of effort involved made me think twice before upgrading my other bigger projects. However, I thought the following might be useful for other people who might be thinking about upgrading their websites.

**1. ////////////// JS:** 
On the File System, replace the js scripts, which are referenced at the bottom of the html/php scripts, with the new versions, which are available at \bower_components\foundation-sites\dist. 
For example, copy \bower_components\foundation-sites\dist\abc.js to yourProject/js/abc.js.

**2. ////////////// SCSS VARIABLES:** 
In the files (_settings.scss), (_custom_styles.scss), etc:

- REPLACE `$paragraph-font-size` WITH `$global-font-size`
- REPLACE `$callout-bg` WITH `$callout-background`
- .... and replace any other variables, which fail the compilation from scss to css

**3. ////////////// PANELS & ALERT BOXES:** 
In php/html: REPLACE the classes (panel) & (alert) WITH the class callout. For me, following are the strings, which I used in the Editor's Replace dialogue (**using regular expressions**). Depending on your design and coding style, you will probably need different strings.

- REPLACE :`<div data-alert class='alert-box **success** round'>`
  WITH    :`<div class='**success** callout' data-closable='slide-out-right'>`
- REPLACE :`<div data-alert class='alert-box **alert** round'>`
  WITH    :`<div class='**alert** callout' data-closable='slide-out-right'>`
- REPLACE :`<a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a>`
  WITH    :`<button class='close-button' aria-label='Dismiss alert' type='button' data-close>   <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>   </button>`
- REMOVE the line: `<script src="./js/foundation.alert.js"></script>`
- To the text inside each alert box, ADD `<p>` around the text message: `<p>...</p>`

**4. ////////////// MENUS:** 
I think the best way of handling menus, is to re-write them from scratch.

**5. ////////////// TABLES:** 
REPLACE :`class='table'`
WITH    :`class='hover'`

**6. ////////////// Make TABLES Responsive (optional):**

- REPLACE :`<table`
  WITH    :`<div class='table-scroll'><table`
- REPLACE :`</table>`
  WITH    :`</table></div>`

**7. ////////////// ABIDE:**

- REPLACE :`</label>(.*)\r\n(.*)<small class=['|"]error['|"]>(.*)</small>` 
  WITH    :`<span class="form-error">$3</span>\r\n$2</label>`
- REPLACE :`<form (.*) data-abide(.*)>`
  WITH    :`<form $1 data-abide novalidate $2>`

**- Custom patterns:**
- use the following 2 lines, instead of the commented lines:

```
// Foundation 6 Style:
Foundation.Abide.defaults.patterns['dd_mm_yyyy'] = /((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.]0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.]\d\d/; 
Foundation.Abide.defaults.patterns['short_time'] = /(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9])/; 

// Foundation 5 Style:
// $(document).foundation({
 // abide : {
   // patterns : {
     // short_time: /(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9])/,
     // dd_mm_yyyy: /((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.]0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.]\d\d/
   // },
  // }
// });
```

**By no means, this is a comprehensive list of all the required changes. If it is, the Foundation team would have published it long time ago. However, it is a starting point, which might provide you with an idea of what is involved.

Good Luck....**

Answer (score 0):

Also found that abide wants custom validators to be defined prior to initialising Foundation 6
eg. I have a phone number validator which is called first

```
// Set Custom validator for Description fields to not accept phone numbers
noPhone(); 
$(document).foundation();
```