# How can I toggle `multi_expand` in a Foundation Accordion at runtime?

Tags: zurb-foundation

Zurb Foundation has `data-options="multi_expand: true"` to allow multiple accordion sections to be expanded simultaneously, however as far as I can tell this option can only be specified in your HTML, so you cannot toggle this at runtime (i.e. to allow users to switch between modes without reloading the page).

I tried changing `data-options="multi_expand: true"` to `false` at runtime, after the page had loaded, and calling `$(document).foundation();` (which is valid, [according to the documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/javascript.html), see "Adding New Content After Page Load"), however this did not have any effect and the accordion retains the `multi_expand` option value it had when the page was first loaded by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

In Foundation 6, you will need to call `Foundation.reInit($('#your-accordion'));` after making any change to `data-options`.

[From the docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#initializing)

> In previous versions of Foundation, there was a method for plugins called `reflow`, though it's inclusion on plugins wasn't universal. For Foundation 6 we've added a global `reInit` method that will remove and reapply event listeners, update the plugin's instance data for relevant information, like a new tab or content pane being added, and reset any cached data the plugin may rely on.

Comment: I think I'm using Foundation 5. Is there a clean and easy upgrade path to Foundation 6?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558589/work-needed-to-upgrade-zurb-foundation-v5-to-v6-2. Might not be clean, easy, or even complete. Personally haven't had to do a migration.